# Standard Component UI Sample

Tags: visualforce

Recently, I started learning Visualforce and apex using trailhead.

Following Visualforce Standard Component reference, there are only sample code and reference but there aren’t UI sample. It’s difficult to know which component to use for the screen I want to create.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref.htm

Is there any site include UI sample of Visualforce standard component?